# execute axios request multiple times only get one output

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; i++) {
    axios.get(`SOME_URL/${subscriptions[i]}`, config1)
        .then((result) => {
            return result.data.subscriptionId
        })
        .then((result) => {
            axios.get(`SOME_URL/${result}/devices`, config2)
                .then((data) => {
                    activationCodeAndDevice[data.data.devices[0].id] = result
                    return activationCodeAndDevice
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);                    
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

Now the console.log(result) will print as many times as the for loop goes through. What is your suggestion to only print the result one time when all the Axios requests are done executing?

Now i did build something like this but with 3 different requests:

```
var request1 = axios.get('request1')
var request2 = axios.get('request2')
var request3 = axios.get('request3') 

Promise.allSettled([request1, request2, request3]) 
.then((values) => {
//do something
})
.catch((err) => {
//do something
})
```

I have no idea on how to get for a request that I have to perform multiple times, depending on an array of values, but only get one time the output. Of course, i could write it in a file and just have a look at the file once the data is written, but i want it to have it on the console.

thanks

Comment: a for loop iteration does not wait for `axios.get` to finish. Use `await` fro both axios calls

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `but only get one time the output`? You only want the first response?

Comment: well, right now the output of the console.log is: ['a'] then when it executes the second time it is ['a','b'] and so on. I only want the console.log(result) to print ['a','b',...'n'] one time at the end when the requests finish and not have all the other console.log printed in between.

Comment: So you want an array of `activationCodeAndDevice` values printed once all requests have finished?

Comment: it is an object of activationCodeAndDevice and only to be printed once when it is done with all elements in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
const promises = subscriptions.map(subscription => axios.get(`SOME_URL/${subscription}`, config1))
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((values) => {
    ...
})
```

The map converts the requests to an array of promises, and the Promise.allSettled waits for the array to succeed.

If you really insist in using a for loop you can also do the following:

```
let promises = [];
for(let i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; i++) {
   promises.push(axios.get(`SOME_URL/${subscription}`, config1));
}
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((values) => {
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
const getSubscriptionResponse = subscriptions.map(subscription => axios.get(`SOME_URL/${subscription}`, config1))
Promise.allSettled(getSubscriptionResponse).then((values) => {
    var subscriptionsValue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        subscriptionsValue.push(values[i].value.data.subscriptionId);
    }
    const getDeviceResponse = subscriptionsValue.map(sub => axios.get(`SOME_URL/${sub}/devices`, config2))
    Promise.allSettled(getDeviceResponse).then((res) => {
        var finalResults = {}
        for (let j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
            finalResults[res[j].value.data.devices[0].id] = subscriptionsValue[j]
        }
        console.log(finalResults);
    })
})
```

this will only print once the finalResult

```
{
A:A,
B:B,
C:C,
.
.
.
}
```

it looks a bit messy with all the for loops but I actually need to get the data from the array of responses.